# Carbon not found PHP project

Tags: php, composer-php

I cannot seem to get Carbon work on my PHP project. 
I'm using Composer and installed Carbon with the following command:

```
Composer require nestbot/carbon;
```

I can see Carbon files in my vendor folder.

```
useCarbon\Carbon;

class Manager {

    public function x()
    {
        Carbon::now();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Carbon\Carbon' not found
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not only use a class but also require autoload file generated by composer:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

class Manager {

    public function x()
    {
        Carbon::now();
    }
}
```

Comment: note that the `require` for the autoloader should be in the bootstrap code for your php system, not at the top of a random class file. If you're using any of the common frameworks, it'll be there already.

Comment: @Spudley definitely.

Comment: Just using pure PHP here guys, the require fixed it. Is there another way to include it without it if im not using any frameworks?

Comment: @MantasStanionis the point is that you should `require` autoload file somewhere and once. If the main entry point of your project is this file - you can require it here. If not - require it in the main file. For example if you use a front-controller pattern - require it there.